# Show that $u^TAu=0\Rightarrow u\in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$ for $A\geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading a proof that assumes $u^TAu=0\Rightarrow u\in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$ for $A\geq 0$. I feel like the proof should be short, but I can't figure it out. I've tried writing A as a Gram matrix but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: @Shubham I mean that A is positive semidefinite -- this is standard notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $A\geq 0$ to note that there exists a symmetric $B\geq 0$ such that $A=BB=B^TB$. Then:
$$
0=u^TAu=u^TB^TBu=||Bu||^2\implies Bu=0\implies Au=B^T(Bu)=0.
$$

Comment: What allows you to write $A=BB$? I know the Cholesky decomposition jumps straight to $A=LL^T$, but these $L$ are not symmetric

Comment: @Dan You can diagonalize $A=Q\Lambda Q^T$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal. Obtain $B$ from $Q\Lambda^{1/2}Q^T$ where $\Lambda^{1/2}$ is also diagonal with the entries being the square roots of the entries of $\Lambda$. By the way, the Cholesky decomposition also works: by the same logic as in the above answer, $A=LL^T$ implies $L^Tu=0$ and so $Au=L(L^Tu)=0$. You don't really need the symmetry of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

For example write $u=\sum c_je_j$, where $e_j$ are the eigenvectors of $A$, with $Ae_j=\lambda_je_j$ and as assumed $\lambda_j\geq 0$. Then $u^TAu=\sum\lambda_j c_j^2$; thus all 
$c_j=0$ whenever $\lambda_j>0$ and $u$ is the sum of zero  eigenvectors.